# Shopware 6 - Email Variables / Shipping Time

Tags: shopware

I have already been able to edit numerous Shopware 6 e-mail templates as required and have found all the variables that I need. Now I am faced with the problem that I would like to display the delivery time / shipping time in the order confirmation. Unfortunately I can't find a variable for this.

Is there perhaps a list of all variables, or does someone have a tip on how I can get the information on the delivery time within the email templates?

Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe try dump() which works in twig. Not sure if it does in emails